# Socketio Bad Config, won't connect/log on connection

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I've been trying to solve this issue through searching this forum and the official documentation to find an answer to my problem, but everything that I've tried has either lead to move problems or been of no help. I'm sure some part of my setup is wrong, and that would be the reason why I'm unable to connect to the nodejs server anymore. This script was working in a different setup yesterday, and today I was stupid enough to try and switch it around to fix a simple bug that it had where it logged a new socket from a single client every second or so. I've been messing around with it to the point where it no longer connects at all, and now I can't undo to the point I was at.

To give some setup knowledge on how the backend looks (if it would be of any help), all of my node modules are in the node_modules sub folder in my public html folder, which is also where my one and only app.js script is. My app.js script is setup as follows:

```
var express = require('express'),
    http = require('http');
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(8002);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.php');
});

console.log(`Server running at http://mywebsiteip:8002/`);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('Client connected');
    client.on('join', function(data) {
       console.log(data);
    });
});

io.on('disconnect', function(data){
    console.log('Client disconnected');  
    });
```

I've left this mostly alone, besides the top 5 lines which have been switched from var to const multiple times and rearranged extensively, but other than that, they're pretty much the same as it was when it worked.

The next batch of code is from the client, which is still pretty much the same besides the actual socketio script link and the following socket io connection script, seen below.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.js" integrity="sha256-bQmrZe4yPnQrLTY+1gYylfNMBuGfnT/HKsCGX+9Xuqo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
            const io = require("socket.io-client");
            const socket = io.connect("https://mywebsiteip:8002", { secure: true, reconnection: true, rejectUnauthorized: false });
            socket.on('connect', function(data) {
            socket.emit('join', 'Hello World from client');
            });
        </script>
```

It is my understanding that this should just output a console line when a user connects to the server, but running the app.js file through bash just logs the line where the server is running. These are the only two files that I've done any editing to, I've seen some others with another server.js file or something but some I've seen don't have that, so I've kept it to this setup thus far. I've been bashing my head at the wall for the last couple hours trying to fix this but nothing has seemed to solve the issue.

Comment: Tried a few more things still no luck..

Comment: Did a bit more editing of the code but there is an error which appears regardless of every change I do to the code; Failed to load resource: `net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
index.js:83 GET http://mywebsite.com:8002/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Myr4qJN net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, we have a few problems here, please adjust all of them in order to have your code running properly:

1 - **On the server side** you wrote like this:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('Client connected');
    client.on('join', function(data) {
       console.log(data);
    });
});
```

In the first line of this piece of code you used as parameter the word **socket** but on the third line you passed **client**, both words should be the same so you code can work.

Maybe by doing this change you may already have solved your problem, but some other can come up, like the following:

2 - **On the cliente side**:
The first line of code on your client socket.io script is written like this

```
const io = require("socket.io-client");
```

Your should not use **require** on your client side code, because it is not a pure javascript command. Basically it will only work on NodeJs and may return an error if you use it like this.

3 - You seem to be using a php file on a NodeJs project, change that to a .html file

I have tried these changes on my local machine and it worked just fine.

Comment: Will give solution to problem, I've since overhauled the entire code to match socket 2.3.0 syntax and have resolved the issues you outlined, on your final point, that isn't possible. While ideally you develop a website in either PHP or Node, I had experience in PHP and wrote the bulk of the code so far in PHP, which is well over 1500 lines. Considering my limited knowledge of Node, this entire translation would be lengthy and overall not an option at this moment. In the future I am considering a full switch to nodejs for ease of future development but at the moment it has to be a PHP file.